# Jaspersoft jsonql iterate over list to get next element

Tags: json, jasper-reports

I am using jaspersoft studio 6.6.0 for my report, and i have json as a datasource for my report, in my report there is a field to display next port name based on condition of current port, but i am not able to display that, my json is as like this

```
"routingLocs": [
            {
                "callOrder": 1,
                "locCode": "ZWTHJ",
                "isCurrentLoc": "N"
            },
            {
                "callOrder": 2,
                "locCode": "TRYAR",
                "isCurrentLoc": "Y"
            },
            {
                "callOrder": 3,
                "locCode": "AUABP",
                "isCurrentLoc": "N"
            },
            {
                "callOrder": 4,
                "locCode": "RAJPI",
                "isCurrentLoc": "N"
            }
        ]
```

now i have to display locCode of object which is next to object that has isCurrentLoc = "Y", for this i have created one field with expression as

`<![CDATA[routingLocs..locCode(^.isCurrentLoc == "Y")]]>`

This expression is printing "TRYAR" instead of "AUABP"

My field definition in JRXML to display the value is

```
<field name="nextPort" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression">
            <![CDATA[routingLocs..locCode(^.isCurrentLoc == "Y")]]>
        </property>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nextPort]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
```

please help me to fix this expression

Thanks in advance for any kind of support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot land on a sibling element with a `jsonql` query, but you can filter the JSON in a separate `subDataset` to achieve what you want.
Provided there is some order in your JSON data, like the ascending order of the `callOrder`, you can start creating your main dataset with your filtering query, something like:

```
<queryString language="jsonql">
    <![CDATA[routingLocs.*(isCurrentLoc == "Y")]]>
</queryString>
```

Then create a subDataset that accepts a `MAIN_CALL_ORDER` parameter and that will use the same JSON data that your main does:

```
<subDataset name="nextPortDataset" uuid="a8b8a64f-4c6b-4c28-91db-e10f28cef52c">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="./DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <parameter name="MAIN_CALL_ORDER" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[routingLocs.*(callOrder > $P{MAIN_CALL_ORDER})[0]]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="locCode" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="locCode"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[locCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>    
</subDataset>
```

Here, the query will produce the first item that has the `callOrder` greater than the one sent from the main dataset.
Then this dataset should be linked to a list that will be passed the parameter like so:

```
<jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
    <datasetRun subDataset="nextPortDataset" uuid="55c7173b-0b04-4d4f-bd80-48cfe1ef620c">
        <datasetParameter name="MAIN_CALL_ORDER">
            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainCallOrder}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
        </datasetParameter>
    </datasetRun>
    <jr:listContents height="30" width="460">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="213ab052-9cdc-419a-8d3d-45db3bf6ef90"/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{locCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>        
    </jr:listContents>
</jr:list>
```

A basic working JRXML would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e9573346-c7d0-4b7a-a838-d2ff5b7b9512">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="./DataAdapter.xml"/>
    <subDataset name="nextPortDataset" uuid="a8b8a64f-4c6b-4c28-91db-e10f28cef52c">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="./DataAdapter.xml"/>
        <parameter name="MAIN_CALL_ORDER" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <queryString language="jsonql">
            <![CDATA[routingLocs.*(callOrder > $P{MAIN_CALL_ORDER})[0]]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="callOrder" class="java.lang.Integer">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="callOrder"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[callOrder]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="locCode" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="locCode"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[locCode]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="isCurrentLoc" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="isCurrentLoc"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[isCurrentLoc]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[routingLocs.*(isCurrentLoc == "Y")]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="mainCallOrder" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="callOrder"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mainCallOrder]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mainLocCode" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="locCode"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mainLocCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mainIsCurrentLoc" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="isCurrentLoc"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mainIsCurrentLoc]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="32" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="4ec73015-1c44-441c-a80e-bff448923a29">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bff05bbe-0c73-4e55-adec-461fd0f2ebff"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[callOrder]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="018825e6-aa24-4a11-85a4-760fa6cf913c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cc7977d7-a541-4d3b-81d8-97be3451e130"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[locCode]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="345" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="16e13486-0a34-4c65-b512-00a4678c65f7">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="82e0773c-3e7d-4372-a44c-93a4bfcfd6b0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[isCurrentLoc]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="60" height="30" uuid="ad4e4685-2696-472c-a3b6-4a9961aeb6dc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bff05bbe-0c73-4e55-adec-461fd0f2ebff"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Main Dataset]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="110" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="3bffc0f6-fb80-443a-b06d-ebbe2b669388">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="bff05bbe-0c73-4e55-adec-461fd0f2ebff"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainCallOrder}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="1267f406-8492-4dd1-859a-a37f24ac545a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="cc7977d7-a541-4d3b-81d8-97be3451e130"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainLocCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="345" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="522f3a23-a2b4-443d-9ca5-9abbd54a07df">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="82e0773c-3e7d-4372-a44c-93a4bfcfd6b0"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainIsCurrentLoc}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="560" height="30" uuid="859af22b-90ec-41fb-acf0-36d4acf2b90a"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="nextPortDataset" uuid="55c7173b-0b04-4d4f-bd80-48cfe1ef620c">
                        <datasetParameter name="MAIN_CALL_ORDER">
                            <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainCallOrder}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                        </datasetParameter>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="560">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="6db9b791-aaac-45e9-af0f-34546254b9e9"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[Filtering List]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="115" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="ee03e48b-38dd-4814-ad7d-2549810c0991">
                                <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                            </reportElement>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{callOrder}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="230" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="213ab052-9cdc-419a-8d3d-45db3bf6ef90"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{locCode}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="345" y="0" width="115" height="30" uuid="a8ea32ea-150f-4d1f-8945-18c2b287c157"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{isCurrentLoc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

and produce the following output:
[image: complete jrxml sample]

This sample needs a file-based data adapter that is linked to both main dataset and subDataset with this property:

```
 <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="./DataAdapter.xml"/>
```

If you don't have a file-based data adapter, you could create one and export it to file from the Repository Explorer inside Jaspersoft Studio.